# Is there a way to get wired internet on a PSP-1000?

Tags: psp

I am trying to update my PSP-1000's firmware. It is at version 2.7.1 with the newest being around 6.6.1. I cannot adjust my security settings to get Wi-Fi, so I was wondering if there was a way to get wired internet on it? My model is the PSP-1000 (the original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to officially get wired internet on the PSP.

But to address your actual problem, you don't need internet on the PSP itself to update it, you just need to connect the system to your PC and copy the update file to its memory stick. Follow the [official guide](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/psp/) on the PlayStation website.

Comment: You can also update the PSP firmware with a copy of a PSP game on a UMD disc. It'll have the minimum necessary version of the firmware to play the game, so the newer the game, the newer the version of the firmware on disc.